# How to verify the files after unzipping from a zip file (7zip)

Tags: zip, unzip, 7zip

How can I verify that the unzipped files are not corrupted **after** the extraction from the zip file?

Scenario: I am packaging some font files via 7zip and then during installation of the application I am unzipping it and copying it to some specific directory. In some cases, although my unzipping is successful my unzipped files are coming to be corrupted. I am not able to load the font files. Upon investigation, I found that they are somehow getting corrupted.

Is it possible that during extraction, extracted files can get corrupted?
What is the way to check if the extracted files are fine or corrupted?

I can test the zip file using **-t** flag which checks that all the files are correctly zipped in the zip files but what I want to check is that **POST** extraction whether the files corrupted or not?

Thanks